# The tuple space distributed computing paradigm for Erlang

Tags: erlang, distributed-computing

There are several languages that implement tuple spaces: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple_space

Has anyone worked with tuple spaces in Erlang as a means of module communication/message passing for distributed computing; if so, what is your experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong about tuple spaces, but ETS looks like it fits the definition on a node-local basis and with mnesia on top it would fit the definition in a distributed fashion. Many Erlang applications use ETS some way or the other, I might add.

If it is suitable depends on how much and how you want to store data.

Comment: I'm using ETS now, and perhaps it could be the mechanism by which I implement the tuple space layer. I'm mostly looking for a design-level discussion of tuple spaces in Erlang, instead of implementation-level. For example, I know roughly HOW I would implement if I decide to do so; what I'm looking for, really, is to have a discussion on whether it's worth it, and whether it would offer any benefit over ETS alone for distributed computing applications in particular.